# Wildcard assembly reference in csproj

Tags: reference, nuget, wildcard, csproj

I'm using nuget (as many of you) a lot for referencing external and internal component-assemblies.
For debugging purposes, it would be nice being able to exchange the nuget-assembly for it's source-code.
Unfortunately, some "core-lib" is used pretty often by the solution itself and also some nuget-referenced packages (used by the sln). Simply removing the reference via VS and adding it's source-project often causes an ambigous relation to the "core-lib", because both (sln and package-src) use the "core-lib" - mostly in different versions.
The only way (I know) to solve that issue is to update all references to the same version (usually, the most actual one). That can be pretty annoying, especially in bigger projects.
Maybe there exists a way to make referencing more flexible - e.g. by using wildcards in the hint-path?

Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using symbol packages ? More details @ http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package